# Live calculations in equation typsetting?

Tags: formatting

I want to put together an equation graphic with a live calculation in it. If I use HoldForm, it retains the formatting I want, but I don't know how to ReleaseHold (or whatever is required) to insert a live calculation.

Here is an example:

```
miles = 3 Sqrt[Pi/4/.02 35 .001];
Show[Graphics[
  Text[Style[
    HoldForm[
     Subscript[G, 3 \[Sigma]] = 
      3 Sqrt[Pi/4/\[Zeta] Subscript[f, n] Subscript[A, in]] = 
       3 Sqrt[Pi/4/.02 35 .011] = 3.517 g' s], Large, 
    FormatType -> TraditionalForm]], ImageSize -> Large]]
```

This does exactly what I want to do except that I have to hard code the value into the final typeset whereas I would prefer to insert the value from the variable "miles."

Thanks for your help!

Comment: try `Text[Style[
  HoldForm[Subscript[G, 3 \[Sigma]] = 
      3 Sqrt[Pi/4/\[Zeta] Subscript[f, n] Subscript[A, in]] = 
       3 Sqrt[Pi/4/.02 35 .001] = # g' s] &@(3 Sqrt[
      Pi/4/.02 35 .001]), Large, FormatType -> TraditionalForm]]`?

Comment: ... or `Text[Style[
  HoldForm[Subscript[G, 3 \[Sigma]] = 
     3 Sqrt[Pi/4/\[Zeta] Subscript[f, n] Subscript[A, in]] = 
      3 Sqrt[Pi/4/.02 35 .001] = x g' s] /. x -> miles, Large, 
  FormatType -> TraditionalForm]]`? Also `Text[Style[
  With[{x = miles}, 
   HoldForm[
    Subscript[G, 3 \[Sigma]] = 
     3 Sqrt[Pi/4/\[Zeta] Subscript[f, n] Subscript[A, in]] = 
      3 Sqrt[Pi/4/.02 35 .001] = x  g' s]], Large, 
  FormatType -> TraditionalForm]]`

Comment: Thanks kglr! The simple replacement rule works well for me!

Answer (score 2):

You can inject `miles` using

```
text = Text[Style[HoldForm[Subscript[G, 3 σ] = 3 Sqrt[Pi/4/ζ Subscript[f, n] 
    Subscript[A, in]] = 3 Sqrt[Pi/4/.02 35 .001] = x g' s] /. x -> miles, 
    Large, FormatType -> TraditionalForm]]
```

or

```
text = Text[Style[ HoldForm[Subscript[G, 3 σ] = 3 Sqrt[Pi/4/ζ 
   Subscript[f, n] Subscript[A, in]] = 3 Sqrt[Pi/4/.02 35 .001] = # g' s] & @ miles, 
   Large, FormatType -> TraditionalForm]]
```

or

```
text = Text[Style[ With[{x = miles}, HoldForm[ Subscript[G, 3 σ] = 3 Sqrt[Pi/4/ζ 
  Subscript[f, n] Subscript[A, in]] = 3 Sqrt[Pi/4/.02 35 .001] = x g' s]], 
  Large, FormatType -> TraditionalForm]]
```

With any of the above

```
Show[Graphics[text, ImageSize -> Large]]
```

gives

[image]